# How can I search for CamelCase words in a buffer using Elisp?

Tags: regular-expressions, search

How can I find CamelCase words in the buffer using Elisp?

Have started with the following but the pattern does not cover all situations of CamelCase.

```
(defun detect-camel-case-words (string)
  "Detect camel case words in the given STRING."
  (let ((start 0)
        (end 0))
    (while (string-match "\\([A-Z][a-z0-9]+\\)" string start)
      (setq end (match-end 1))
      (setq start end)) ))
```

Comment: Edited to just one question.

Comment: what's your definition of camel case? what words is it failing on?